# Read-only property doesn't have value. Why it isn't error?

Tags: swift, protocols

```
protocol Named {
    var name: String { get }
}

protocol Aged {
    var age: Int { get }
}


struct Person: Named, Aged {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
```

In this code, I inherit Named and Aged protocol which have to write at least read-only property in sub.

But Struct person just declare type(String, Int), not the value.

I think at least declare the value. But there is no error.

What did I missing?

```
Named {
    var name: String { get }
}

protocol Aged {
    var age: Int { get }
}


struct Person: Named, Aged {
    var name: String = "Steeve"
    var age: Int = 20
}
```

Comment: There's a big difference between declaring your `Person` struct and trying to create instances of the `Person` struct.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got my misderstanding of that. I confuse declaring and create instance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> But Struct person just declare type(String, Int), not the value.

The values are assigned when you create an instances of the `Person` struct, e.g.:

```
let joe = Person(name: "Joe", age: 23)
let mary = Person(name: "Mary", age: 35)
```

Each instance of `Person` has its own set of values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I create an instance, in that time I assigned values. Thank you :)